# What do you call it when a baby raises his/her lower lip when he/she is about to cry?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a word for this action? The action could lead to a full on crying or not.

Comment: I would call it a "pout".

Comment: @HotLicks Marilyn Monroe pouted, babies merely quiver their lips!

Comment: I, on the other hand, keep a stiff upper lip...on top of my loose, flabby chin! This is Brit-lingo, innit!

Comment: @PeterPoint - http://cdn.skim.gs/images/v1/msi/ctli3tooglmspaxsaewg/you-might-want-to-watermark-photos-of-your-children

Comment: @HotLicks Good gracious me! That's a bit scary, don't ya know. I'd call that a curled lower lip, wouldn't you? Pouty it ain't. Now for a full-on pouty lip, please Google 'pouty lips images'

Comment: It's what I would call a pout.

Comment: Well, you should know, hot lips! Ain't you the Louisville Lip?